# Errors trying to compile multiple c++ files with mex for MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, compiler-errors, header-files, mex

I am using **MATLAB** under Ubuntu and want to compile a set of 2 **c++** files with a header file, using **mex**. I show a basic example and the errors I am getting.

This code produces the text "hello" from the c++ function that begins from the mexFunction and is compiled in MATLAB using mex, (mex mexTryAlex.cpp):

```
#include <mex.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void newfunc(){
    cout<<"hello\n";   
}
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) 
{ 
    newfunc();
}
```

and it works normally. Now I try to use *multiple* files and a header file with mex. I create a header file `try.h`:

```
#ifndef try_h
#define try_h
void newfunc();
#endif
```

and then the new function's file `try.cpp`:

```
#include <mex.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <try.h>
using namespace std;

void newfunc(){
    cout<<"hello\n";   
}
```

These 3 files do not compile with `mex`:

```
>> mex  mexTryAlex.cpp try.cpp try.h

Warning: You are using gcc version "4.4.3-4ubuntu5)".  The version
     currently supported with MEX is "4.3.4".
     For a list of currently supported compilers see: 
     http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release/

try.cpp:4:17: error: try.h: No such file or directory
mex: compile of ' "try.cpp"' failed.
??? Error using ==> mex at 208
Unable to complete successfully.
```

Another attempt with using the `-I` option:

```
>> mex  -I mexTryAlex.cpp try.cpp try.h
Warning: You are using gcc version "4.4.3-4ubuntu5)".  The version
     currently supported with MEX is "4.3.4".
     For a list of currently supported compilers see: 
     http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release/

mexTryAlex.cpp:1:17: error: mex.h: No such file or directory
mexTryAlex.cpp:7: error: ‘mxArray’ has not been declared
mexTryAlex.cpp:7: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘mxArray’ with no type
mexTryAlex.cpp:7: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
mex: compile of ' "mexTryAlex.cpp"' failed.
??? Error using ==> mex at 208
Unable to complete successfully.
```

How can I get these files to compile?

Comment: Just a general advice: `using namespace std;` is not the best of ideas. Just use `std::cout`, or if you use `cout` a lot and want to abbreviate it, use `using std::cout;`, but opening up the ***entire std namespace*** will give you headaches in the long run :) Just look around here on SO for pros/cons/discussions about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

The error was fixed by using

```
#include "try.h"
```

instead of

```
 #include <try.h>
```

in the source files.